# Change the decimal places of an existing number in bignumber.js?

Tags: javascript, bignum, bignumber.js

If I've got a BigNumber (http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) with a particular `DECIMAL_PLACES`:

```
let BN = BigNumber.another({ DECIMAL_PLACES: 0 })
a = new BN(10)
```

How can I change the number of decimal places used for a particular operation?

For example:

```
> a.div(3)
3
> a.setDecimalPlaces(1).div(3)
3.3
```

I know I can create a `new BigNum(…)`:

```
> (new BigNumber(a)).div(3)
3.333…
```

But that seems less than ideal.

Comment: `BN.set({ DECIMAL_PLACES: 5 });` and you may work with higher precision by default, then use the `.round(0)` to return particular results

Comment: Ah, so it needs to be done at the class level and not the instance level?